# How to add Master page background Image in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

How to add Master page background Image in ASP .Net

```
body {
           background-image: url(../Images/images1.jpg) no-repeat;
           background-attachment: fixed;
            margin-top: 0px;
 }
```

this is not working

Answer (score 2):

try this:-

```
    html { 

        background: url(Jellyfish.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 

        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: this not working i am using this code in master page css

Comment: maybe its a path issue, as mentioned in this link, See if this link helps you:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666540/setting-background-image-in-asp-net-master-page